# Bearer Tokens in C++Builder/FMX REST Functionality?

Tags: rest, jwt, firemonkey, c++builder

I have a server application running in node.js/Mongoose/MongoDB with a REST interface.

My client application is built in Embarcadero C++Builder/Firemonkey(FMX) and so far all is good with interacting with the node server using the embarcadero REST features (TRESTClient/TRESTRequest/TRESTResponse).

I recently added authentication to my server using JSON Web tokens and the user registration/login is working successfully, giving me back a bearer token using the following code:

```
const token = jwt.sign({sub: user.id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '30d' })
```

Accessing data is implemented via express-jwt by sending a REST request with the bearer token. Postman makes it easy to send a request for data using a Bearer token (https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#bearer-token), however I cannot find out how to do this seemingly simple task using Embarcadero's REST features.

I have tried using the Embarcadero REST OAUTH/OAUTH2/SIMPLE/BASIC authentication methods with the bearer token in the Access-Token and Request-Token fields and nothing seems to work.

How can this be done? I am sure this is something simple I am missing but there is next to no documentation I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer for anyone else who is having trouble using authentication in C++Builder with REST:

- Design-time method:
  --> Setup TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, TRESTResponse
  --> In TRESTRequest Params, create a new param with fields:

```
Name: Authorization, Value: Bearer XXXXXXXX (JWT String), Options: poDoNotEncode (this is the important part
```

- Creating the REST client for authorization at runtime:

```
// initialize REST client
    TRESTClient* pRESTClient = new TRESTClient(BASE_URL);
    pRESTClient->ContentType = "application/json";
// connect REST request for querying server
    TRESTRequest* pRESTRequest = new TRESTRequest(NULL);
    pRESTRequest->Client = pRESTClient;
// connect REST response for receiving JSON from server
    TRESTResponse* pRESTResponse = new TRESTResponse(NULL);
    pRESTRequest->Response = pRESTResponse;
    pRESTResponse->ContentType = "text/html";

// do authenticated query
    pRESTRequest->Method = rmGET;
    pRESTRequest->Resource = ROUTE_ITEMS;
    pRESTRequest->ResourceSuffix = SUBROUTE_ITEMSUFFIX;

    pRESTRequest->Params->Clear();
    TRESTRequestParameter* param = pRESTRequest->Params->AddItem();
    param->Name = "Authorization";
    param->ContentType = ctNone;
    param->Kind = pkHTTPHEADER;
    param->Options << poDoNotEncode;
    char temp[512];
    sprintf(temp, "Bearer %s", JWT_TOKEN);
    param->Value = (const char*)temp;

    pRESTRequest->Execute();
```

The server response is then added to the TRESTResponse->Content field as JSON.

As a note, it is important to have the server configured with express-JWT (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt) for this to work properly with the following code managing the server (node.js):

```
app.use(jwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  credentialsRequired: false,
  getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
      return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
  }
}));
```